# How do I license code when rewriting code in another language?

Tags: derivative-works, relicensing, bsd, agpl-3.0, porting

I took the [C code](https://git.xiph.org/?p=mirrors/theora.git;a=blob;f=examples/png2theora.c;h=c740ad8043848738909c09b07135d7cedb9e5fff;hb=refs/heads/master) from the `png2theora` example tool of Xiph.Org Theora which has a copyright header:

```
/********************************************************************
 *                                                                  *
 * THIS FILE IS PART OF THE OggTheora SOFTWARE CODEC SOURCE CODE.   *
 * USE, DISTRIBUTION AND REPRODUCTION OF THIS LIBRARY SOURCE IS     *
 * GOVERNED BY A BSD-STYLE SOURCE LICENSE INCLUDED WITH THIS SOURCE *
 * IN 'COPYING'. PLEASE READ THESE TERMS BEFORE DISTRIBUTING.       *
 *                                                                  *
 * THE Theora SOURCE CODE IS COPYRIGHT (C) 2002-2009,2009           *
 * by the Xiph.Org Foundation and contributors http://www.xiph.org/ *
 *                                                                  *
 ********************************************************************

  function: example encoder application; makes an Ogg Theora
            file from a sequence of png images
  last mod: $Id$
             based on code from Vegard Nossum

 ********************************************************************/
```

The [COPYING file](https://git.xiph.org/?p=mirrors/theora.git;a=blob;f=COPYING;h=c8ccce4ffb5d7a7574bac87429ec1d2a7b90686d;hb=refs/heads/master) points is a 3-clause BSD license.

I have taken the code apart into several pieces which I have rewritten in Vala code classes (so in a different programming language).

I also wrote several vapi files to bind to the C APIs (for libtheora, libogg and libpng).

I did several heavy changes to the code:

- Replaced return code based error handling by exception handling
- Rewrote command line parsing from getopt to GLib OptionGroup
- Reorganized the code into several classes
- Replaced stdio file functions by gio classes
- Added some additional error handling

So I have almost completely rewritten the original code, but it should still work essentially like the original tool from the user perspective.

Now I would like to release this code (preferably under an AGPLv3 license).

How do I correctly attribute the original authors copyright / license in this case?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The other question is about porting MIT licensed code. The answer would be very different if this was asking about porting GPL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under some interpretations, re-writing code to a different language constitutes a derivative work. Under others it doesn't.

If you hold your work not to be a derivative work (in the copyright sense of the word), you're done; you don't have anything to do with the original work anymore, and you can license whichever way you like without attributing the original authors.

I you do hold your work to be a derivative work, which is the safer, and IMO correct route, you have to comply with the 3-clause BSD license. The first two are the most relevant:

> - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
>     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

The most practical way to comply in my opinion is to include the BSD notice in the project, and have a central notice that remarks it was based on the original work, link to the original work and original authors file, and then do your standard stuff for the new license.

Comment: I have retained the BSD license, so am now viewing my rewrite as a derivative work: https://github.com/promi/png2theorav (I hope that I've done everything correctly)

Comment: @Promi if I were you I'd make it more clear that the BSD only counts for the original work. If I were to look for a license, I'd first look at the COPYING file, and it doesn't make it clear that that's only for the original work, not for this work. YMMV

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've switched the naming scheme of the COPYING files around and updated the readme file.

Comment: Your opinion on the issue of it being or not a derivative work is completely irrelevant. The only valid opinion on the matter is the one of the court, in case you get dragged in front of one by a copyright owner who happens to disagree.